# Generic type of React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

What is the generic type of a React Component?

Components could be from classes such as:

```
export class MaskCompanyList extends React.Component<MaskCompanyListProps, MaskCompanyListState> {
    public render() {
        ...
    }
}

export class MaskPersonDetail extends React.Component<MaskPersonDetailProps, MaskPersonDetailState> {
    public render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to create this generic class, but I get an error for missing properties:

Not working generic:

```
private getMask<T, R>(): React.Component<T, R> {
    return <MaskCompanyList />;
}
```

Error message from TSLint:

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<T, R, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2 more.
```

The class component class `React.Component<A, B>` is always the same, but the Classes of

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @bsapaka Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `getMask`, the return signature is a react component, but you are returning a react element.

To type a component:

```js
private getMaskComponent(): React.ComponentType<MaskCompanyListProps> {
  return MaskCompanyList;
}
```

To type an element:

```
private getMaskElement(): React.ReactElement {
  return <MaskCompanyList />
}
```